# Call mysqldb SP Error

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I'm trying to call a stored procedure on my database... it returns the result but gives me an error..

**here's the error.**
`**Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now**`

**my model**

```
  function call_procedure($procedure, $parameters = array()) {
      $result = $this->db->query("CALL ".$procedure);
      return $result->result_array();
  }
```

**here's the PS of my error**
[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Give a space between `CALL` and `$procedure` `$this->db->query("CALL ".$procedure);`

Comment: @Vinie yes I did... but I happen to solved this problem... it seems that `CI` doesn't allow multiple select calls at the same time...